# Why is JavaScript being added to header as application/oembed?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, html, scripts

I created a short JavaScript file and placed it in my theme's JS folder, the contents of the file are:

```
/**
 * Text2Give Functions File
 *
 * Mobile Landing Page Functions File
 */

jQuery( function( $ ) {
  "use strict";

  // bind change event to select
  $('#text2give').on('change', function () {
      var url = $(this).val();
      if (url) {
          window.location = url; // redirect
      }
      return false;
  } )
} );
```

I've added it to be enqueued along with all the other JS scripts in my functions.php file like so:

```
    // Add script for landing page for text2give
if ( is_page( 'text2give') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'text2give', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/text2give.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20170614', true  );
}
```

It doesn't work when I load the above referenced page and when I view source I see the following:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://liquidchurch.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fliquidchurch.com%2Ftext2give%2F"/>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="https://liquidchurch.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fliquidchurch.com%2Ftext2give%2F&#038;format=xml"/>
```

All the other scripts look like this:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://liquidchurch.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>`

Any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: not totally sure but one thing to check is the last parameter set to true (`$in_footer`) which means the script will not end up in `<head>`? try changing it to false.

Comment: Can you try it without the `if ( is_page( 'text2give') ) {}` and see if it loads?

Comment: It's not! Those oEmbed link tags are not related to your script being enqueued or not. This is added by core.

Comment: ... and make sure to have `wp_footer()` in your page template if you're want to load scripts in footer.

Comment: I renamed the file text2give-js.js to make it easier for me to distinguish between the page (text2give) and the JS file - this revealed that @birgire was absolutely right - I was mistaking JSON and XML versions of the text2give page for being the JS script (gahh!). I also changed the footer value to false. I can see that text2give-js.js is being loaded in the header via view source, but the code still doesn't work.

Comment: glad to hear you had progress there, also make sure to have an   HTML element with `id="text2give"` that can trigger the change ... just checked, you're using `id="txt2give"` ;-)

Comment: @birgire - just noticed that myself! gotta love those super simple mistakes that crap the entire thing out! If you want to add answer, I will accept...everything is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *oEmbed* discovery link tags are added by core in `wp_oembed_add_discovery_links()` since version 4.4. See the changeset [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/34903/trunk/src/wp-includes/embed-functions.php).

When we enqueue scripts in the footer, we have to make sure the `wp_footer()` is not missing.

There was a typo in the enqueued script here, since the HTML select tag had `id="txt2give"` but not `id="text2give"`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help! I may have been staring at this code for a long time before noticing those issues, great to have a second pair of eyes!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, yes sometimes it helps to sleep on it or get some fresh eyes to look at it ;-)